# Installing previous version of Thunderbird

Tags: release-juno, thunderbird

I'm anxious to install the new version of Elementary Juno but it has Thunderbird 60 in its repos which has killed some of the extensions that I rely on. I currently have that package on hold with Freya. 
How do I install, or does Elementary provide, older packaged versions of Thunderbird? I know I can download older versions from Mozilla directly, but I always run into issues when I do that and the integration doesn't seem work correctly. 
I've been holding off upgrading Thunderbird due to this change so I'll have to wait and hope that the extensions I need are updated soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is pretty simple, first you need to check if there's a version available through apt (in your case exists)

```
$ apt policy thunderbird
thunderbird:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Tabla de versión:
     1:60.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

then you install the older version with the command

```
$ sudo apt install thunderbird=1:52.7.0+build1-0ubuntu1
```

and finally you tell apt to hold on that pakage (that way you can do upgrades on the system and thunderbird will stay on that version)

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold thunderbird
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I'll check this out.  This is what I did to revert my current install, but being a new release I was doubtful that an older port would exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are also ways to « force » use of not compatible extensions in TB…

https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/search.php?search_id=447160902

In TB go to edit → preferences → advanced → advanced settings

( it's the « about config » like in Firefox )

There look for **extensions.strictCompatibility** and set it from true to false by double-clicking on it.

That *may* temporarily help you for the time before such extensions get updated but it's just a *not-so-safe workaround*, remember to set it again to true once your favorite extensions are compatible anew.